# repeated eigenvalue with one independent equation, dimension needed

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The $3\times3$ matrix is:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}    
2 & -2 & 3\\   
-2& -1 & 6\\  
1 &  2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$\lambda_1=-5, \lambda_2=3$ (repeated) I am concerned about $\lambda=3$

So a $3\times3$ matrix has a repeated eigenvalue and another single eigenvalue.
Finding the eigenvectors of the repeated eigenvalue. I just have one equation:

$x+2y-3z=0$ (3 times the same equation)

If I put zero for $x,y,z$ one at each time i got $3$ different independent eigenvectors.
but the dimension of eigenspace can't exceed $2$ as the algebraic order of the eigenvalue is only $2$.

What I am doing wrong? Should I just select 2 of the 3 equations I have in random?

Edit: The eigenvectors I get are: (0 3 2), (3 0 1), (-2 1 0)

Comment: Can you actually tell us what the matrix is? It's hard to help you otherwise...

Comment: not sure if you are notified but i added the matrix, thanks for feedback

Comment: OK, now one more thing: what are the three eigenvectors you get? What do you mean by ""If I put zero for $x,y,z$"? I think this is where you made your mistake, but I don't know exactly what you did so I can't help you yet.

Comment: Can you prove your claim "got 3 different independent eigenvectors"?

Comment: I think you are right, that's where I am wrong but I am a bit confused if you could help me clarify why I am wrong I would be glad. thank you a lot

Comment: (0 3 2) = 2 (3 0 1) + 3 (-2 1 0)

Comment: oh no... I thought since there is a zero at a different place at each eigenvector they would be for sure independent! thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your work is correct. Now you have: $x=3z-2y$, and this is the eigenspace (that has dimension $2$). You can choose: $y=0,z=1$ and you have the eigenvector $(3,0,1)^T$ or $y=1,z=0$ and you have the eigenvector $(-2,1,0)^T$.

Comment: Okay, thank you, so the dimension is 2 and I am not allowed to put x=0